# How to filter datview to show data from last year and current year in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, filter

I have a dataview web part displaying data from a list which I've designed using SharePoint designer. How do I filter it so that I show data from last year as well as the current year?

Note: It should be dynamic, keep changing based on the current date. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool like U2U CAML builder to create a dynamic CAML query to put into the select command of the DVWP. This would be dynamic in that the CAML would utilize an offsetdays based off of [Today].

Comment: Thanks for replying. I can't use 3rd party tools but your comment gave me an idea: using CAML query to do it. Found out just what I wanted here: [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/02/25/filtering-and-formatting-with-date-values.aspx)

Comment: The tool is just used for building the CAML which in turn you'd put into the Select Command of the generated DVWP.